# Ranked Frequency Distributions from Nominal Variables in R

Tags: r, distribution, frequency-distribution

I have searched through the website but have been unable to find a solution to my problem. I have a sample dataset as follows:

```
id,l1
1,3
2,5
3,6
1,5
2,4
3,6
```

id is a nominal variable and represents a unique user and the other is a count variable.

What I want is to find out the distribution of l1 by user. So, looking at my given dataset, id=1 has total l1 = 8; id = 2 has total l1 =  9 and id=3 has total l1 = 12.

I am trying to find out the distribution of l1 according to id but I am stuck. I cannot figure out how to group the relevant columns together and then find the distribution or at least construct a histogram. I can construct a histogram with one variable but I cannot construct a ranked frequency distribution by a nominal variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `base` `R` approach would be to use `tapply`

If your data.frame was called `aa`

```
sumById <- with(aa, tapply(l1,id, sum)))

barplot(sumById)
```

[image]

If you wanted to plot your results without explicitly presumarizing, then you could use `ggplot2` and `stat_summary`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aa, aes(x = id, y = l1)) + stat_summary(fun.y = 'sum', geom = 'bar')
```

[image]